# group dishes with common ingredients

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I am working on below question:

> Suppose you have a list of Dishes, where each dish is associated with
>   a list of ingredients. Group together dishes with common ingredients.

**For example:**

Input:

```
"Pasta" -> ["Tomato Sauce", "Onions", "Garlic"] 
"Chicken Curry" --> ["Chicken", "Curry Sauce"] 
"Fried Rice" --> ["Rice", "Onions", "Nuts"] 
"Salad" --> ["Spinach", "Nuts"] 
"Sandwich" --> ["Cheese", "Bread"] 
"Quesadilla" --> ["Chicken", "Cheese"]
```

Output:

```
("Pasta", "Fried Rice") 
("Fried Rice, "Salad")
("Chicken Curry", "Quesadilla")
("Sandwich", "Quesadilla")
```

Also what is the time and space complexity?

I came up with below code. Is there any better way to do this problem? It looks like algorithm is connected components from graph theory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> ing1 = Arrays.asList("Tomato Sauce", "Onions", "Garlic");
    List<String> ing2 = Arrays.asList("Chicken", "Curry Sauce");
    List<String> ing3 = Arrays.asList("Rice", "Onions", "Nuts");
    List<String> ing4 = Arrays.asList("Spinach", "Nuts");
    List<String> ing5 = Arrays.asList("Cheese", "Bread");
    List<String> ing6 = Arrays.asList("Chicken", "Cheese");

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Pasta", ing1);
    map.put("Chicken Curry", ing2);
    map.put("Fried Rice", ing3);
    map.put("Salad", ing4);
    map.put("Sandwich", ing5);
    map.put("Quesadilla", ing6);

    System.out.println(group(map));
}

private static List<List<String>> group(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    List<List<String>> output = new ArrayList<>();

    if (map == null || map.isEmpty()) {
        return output;
    }

    Map<String, List<String>> holder = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<String> value = entry.getValue();
        for (String v : value) {
            if (!holder.containsKey(v)) {
                holder.put(v, new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            holder.get(v).add(key);
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<List<String>>(holder.values());
}
```

Comment: I am no DSA expert but this is exactly how I would approach the problem. As for time complexity in relation to the map, there are two options for each ingredient, a dish either contains them or doesn't. That leads me to believe that complexity is around 2^n and is definitely exponential so I suppose there may be a better way.

Comment: There may or may not be a _better_ way, depending on how you care to define "better".  But this looks like a perfectly good way.

Answer (score 2):

We can have an actual complexity estimation of this approach using graph theory. A "connected components" approach would have `O(|V| + |E|)` complexity, where `V` is the set of all *ingredients* **and** *dishes*, and `E` is the set containing all relations `(a, b)` where each `a` is a dish and `b` is an ingredient of the dish `b`. (i.e. assuming that you are storing this graph `G = (V, E)` in an adjacency list, as opposed to an adjacency matrix)

In any algorithm that needs to find out all the ingredients of each dish to find the result, you would have to investigate each and every dish and **all** of their ingredients. This would result in an investigation (i.e. traversal) that takes `O(|V| + |E|)` time, which would mean that no *such* algorithm could be better than your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first turn this problem into a graphs problem. Each dish and each ingredient will be a `vertex`. Each relation between dish and ingredient will be an `edge`.

Let's analyse the maximal size of the solution. Assuming there are `N` dishes and `M` ingredients overall, the maximal solution output is when every single dish is related. In that case the output is of size `N^2` so this is a lower bound on the time complexity you can achieve. We can quite easily create a input for which we will must iterate over all vertices and edges so another lower bound on time complexity is `N * M`. Also we must save all of the vertices and edges so `M * N` is a lower bound on space complexity.

Now let's analyse your solution. You iterate over all dishes = `N` and for each one of the dishes you iterate over all of the values = `M` and with `O(1)` you check if in the dictionary so in total `O(N * M)`. Your space complexity is `O(M * N)` as well. I would say your solution is good.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to build a reverse map here.

I think you can write the code in a more expressive way by using `Stream` API introduced in Java8.

Basic steps:

- Extract all the ingredients from the map
- For each ingredient, get a set of dishes, and you will have many such sets - collect all such sets into a set - and so the return-type of the method becomes `Set<Set<String>>`

The following is the implementation:

```java
private static Set<Set<String>> buildReverseMap(Map<String, Set<String>> map) {
    // extracting all the values of map in a Set
    Set<String> ingredients = map.values()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());


    return ingredients.stream()
            // map each ingredient to a set
            .map(s ->
                    map.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(s))
                            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

### Time complexity analysis:

Assuming you have `N` dishes and `M` ingredients, and in worst case each dist can have every ingredient. For each ingredient you need to iterate through every dish and check whether this contains the current-ingredient or not. This check can be done in amortized `O(1)` as we can have ingredients as `HashSet<String>` for each dish.

So for each ingredient you will iterate through every dish and check whether that dish contains this ingredient or not in amortized `O(1)`. This give the time complexity to be amortized `O(M*N)`.

### Space-complexity Analysis:

Simply `O(M*N)` as in worst case you can have every dist made up of every available ingredient.

#### Note:

You can return a `List<Set<String>>` instead of `Set<Set<String>>` just by changing `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` to `.collect(Collectors.toList())`